# how to parse xml using sax by checking both parent and child tags at a time?

Tags: java, sax

Hi 
I want to parse an xml doc using sax parser. What i want to do is to check out both outer and inner tags(Eg: am having same tags in other tags also. like . ) so i want to get the data based on outer tag i.e only from tag or tag1 in our case. can u please help me with this? can i check both the parent and child tags using sax in java???? Please help me out.

Thanks..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that SAX is event-driven and does not hold the entire XML-tree in memory. I think you have to use DOM for this. You should be able to use your SAX-parser to build a DOM-tree.

Answer (score 4):

Write a ContentHandler that utilises a Stack to hold data of nested elements. In the beginning of StartElement do Stack.push and in the end of EndElement do Stack.pop. Use a Stack holding just element names or Stack with your own Element class to hold more data.

You may also write a general purpose abstract ContentHandler that holds the Stack and provides its descendants methods for getting all kinds of information of the current element and its path.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way you can do is, if the outer tags are different then when u get the outer tag can set some variable value, then when it comes to inner tag can check which value that variable is set to and know parent tag. 
for

```
Ex: 
<x>
 <y/>
</x>
<z>
 <y/>
</z>
```

so in startElement() of handler you can check if name==x, set variable value to x( else z). when you get y, check what the variable is set to(x/z).